# What scriptures describe juice coming from Ganesha's cheeks covering Kailash?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, ganesha, kailasa

The Sankalpa Suryodaya is a play by the 13th century Sri Vaishnava Acharya Vedanta Desikan.  At one point in the play, a king goes around the world in a Vimana looking for a good place to meditate. He visits various sacred places, but rejects most of them for various reasons. Here is the reason he gives for Mount Kailash:

> Though occupied by the lord who overthrew Manmatha, Mount Kailash is no fit place for uninterrupted meditation.  **The juice flowing from the mountainlike cheeks of Vinayaka and bubbling like the dark waves of the Yamuna covers the whole place as with black paint.**

The lord who overthrew Manmatha is Shiva.  But I'm interested in the part in bold.  My question is, what scriptures describe Ganesha covering Mount Kailash with juice coming from his cheeks?

[image: Image of mount kailash]

Also, it says the juice covers the place "as with black paint".  So does scripture give that as the reason for the black appearance of the mountain?

Comment: I think Swami Desikan is poetically referring to the elephant rut that oozes from Vinayaka's temples (not cheeks).